# How to find specific clients in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

There are Client A and Client B connected to socket io.

Client A has C B's socket.id object information.

C B was refreshed and socket.id value changed.

CA wants to talk to CB only.

However, the socket.id in the CB has changed. **Big Problem**

The way I figured

1. Create a Client object in Js with io.connect.
2. Set the socket ID of C B to the first setting value (socket.id received when first connecting) every time it is refreshed.
3. C A gets the socket.id value of the CB of the Client object.

Is this the way it is?

```
enter code here
//test.js
var Clients = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('whenever refresh',function(data){
        Clients[data] = socket.id
    });
});



//test.html
<script>
var socket = io();

socket.on('whenever refresh',"B");
```

Comment: As you've discovered `socket.id` is good only for the duration of that socket.  If you want a lasting reference, then you need to invent something like a username that stays the same everytime the user connects.  When a connection happens on the server, you can either see what user it is from a cookie or you can have the user announce who they are with a message.  Then, once you know who the user is, your server can connect two users by name and that will work every time they connect or refresh because it does not rely on `socket.id` which changes.

Comment: Is `C B` the short form for `Client B`?

Comment: Yes C B is Client B